# Embedded YouTube Video to Auto Play Muted?

Tags: youtube, embed

I have 6 videos on my site and i've added autoplay and loop to them, but i would like them to play with no audio, how can i do that ?

This is how the code looks `https://www.youtube.com/embed/s0qLJ4geZko?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=s0qLJ4geZko`

If i'm allowed to post the link to my site, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should add mute=1 to the string in order to play it in mute by default...

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/s0qLJ4geZko?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&playlist=s0qLJ4geZko
```

Answer (score -2):

Apparently they already play muted, so problem solved.